# vim-clang-format: clang-format is not found

Tags: vim, clang, vim-plugin

I installed `clang-format` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with `sudo apt install clang-format` and the installation was successful. I can execute `clang-format-6.0` now, but when I use `ClangFormat` in vim, it tells me that "clang-format is not found". How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check what is contained in the package `clang-format-6.0` (`dpkg -L clang-format-6.0`) you will find that it does not install `clang-format` into the `/usr/bin` directory. But you will find that it does install it to `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin` instead.

**One possible solution would be to add `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin` to your `PATH` variable**. Under this path `clang-format` is available. The command `/usr/bin/clang-format-6.0` is just a symbolic link to it, so it should be equivalent to using `clang-format-6.0`. Why the package maintainer decided to not link `/usr/bin/clang-format` as well is not clear to me.

If you are unsure how to do that you may want to look it up here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables